# How to mark read files in dataflow?

Tags: python, etl, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, windowing

I am using dataflow to read files from GCS bucket and do some transformations on it. I am using beam.io.ReadFromText() method for that.

What is the best way to mark the files that are already read, so that same file will not repeatedly read by dataflow ?

Answer (score 1):

A Dataflow job using `beam.io.ReadFromText` will read each file that matches the given pattern exactly once.  I assume from your question you're trying to run a pipeline multiple times and only read files that showed up in the GCS bucket since the last run? In that case, you have two options.

(1) Use `apache_beam.io.textio.ReadFromTextWithFilename` and then record the set of filenames that you already read somewhere (e.g. write them to a text file) that you consult when constructing the set of files to read on your next run, or

(2) Use `apache_beam.io.textio.ReadAllFromText` to read from a PCollection of filenames, which is computed to be the set of things that exist in your bucket (e.g. using `apache_beam.io.fileio.MatchFiles`) but were not read in any previous run (recorded as in (1) via a separate output file in GCS).

It might be worth considering if a streaming pipeline would better meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to set up a cloud storage trigger which publishes the name of each file uploaded to the storage bucket as a separate PubSub message to the Topic of your choosing (i.e. `projects/PROJECT_ID/topics/TOPIC_NAME`).

You can then set up a streaming dataflow pipeline which ingests these PubSub messages via `beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic='projects/PROJECT_ID/topics/TOPIC_NAME')`, from which the filename can be extracted and the data from the file read using `beam.io.ReadAllFromText()`. You can then continue the pipeline with your own custom transformations.

This pattern negates the need to track the files which have already been transformed as each file is automatically transformed as soon as it is uploaded to the bucket.

I came across the following useful link which could assist with the details of implementing the above pattern (see the *'Streaming processing of GCS files'* subsection). https://medium.com/@pavankumarkattamuri/input-source-reading-patterns-in-google-cloud-dataflow-4c1aeade6831

Hope this helps!